# redirecting www.foo.com to www.bar.com

Tags: php, javascript, apache, forward

Hay guys, I'm having a bit of an issue.

Say i have the domain www.foo.com, but this domain is framed-forwarded to www.bar.com.

www.foo.com is still in the address bar, but i now need to redirect www.foo.com to www.bar.com. So when you hit foo.com, you get redirected to bar.com.

I tried doing this in PHP, but it seems that all the $_SERVER variables are relative to bar.com (because of the framed forwarding). I also tried to get the URL using javascript, but again this failed.

How could i redirect www.foo.com to www.bar.com?

Oh, and i don't have access to the domain, i only have FTP.

The server is apache, and i have access to PHP.

Most important thing I forgot to tell:

## I don't have access to www.foo.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be sending a header 301 using PHP. You could add the following code to the file `index.php` inside the domain `www.bar.com`.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'foo.com') !== false)
{
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://www.bar.com/');
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, i can't detect if the user is viewing www.foo.com because of the framed forwading.

Comment: Do you own both domains and do they serve pages from the same directory?

Comment: Pretty much. I don't have access to foo.com, but i have access to bar.com. There's nothing under www.foo.com. It's just a frame-forward to bar.com.

Comment: If you are redirecting the user, he won't even be able to view `www.foo.com`. :-)

Comment: @michiel - I don't have access to www.foo.com. I need to work within the bar.com domain.

Comment: I don't have access to the www.foo.com domain.

Comment: @dotty: I have updated my answer. Currently, when you go to `www.foo.com`, it is displaying `www.foo.com` in the address bar, but displaying the contents of `www.bar.com` right?

Comment: @michiel - Correct. The HTTP_HOST says www.bar.com.

Comment: @dotty: You could read the address bar using JavaScript. For example using `window.location.href`.

Comment: @dotty: Or if you are using frames it would be `parent.location.href`.

Comment: parent.location.href says undefined and window.location.href says bar.com

Comment: actually, parent.location says "Permission denied for <http://www.bar.co.uk> to get property Location.href"

Comment: @dotty: And if you echo `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, does it display your IP address or the IP address of your server?

Comment: Then you could determine whether the user has navigated to `www.foo.com` or `www.bar.com`. If the value of `REMOTE_ADDR` contains the server's IP address then the user has navigated to `www.foo.com`. If it is any other IP address, then the user has navigated to `www.bar.com`.

Comment: Seems that PHP's header() function doesn't have the ability to redirect the browser, only the frame. This seems to be the biggest issue.

Comment: @dotty: You could add a small JavaScript to the page. For example: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>parent.location.href = 'http://www.bar.com/';</script>";`

Comment: @dotty: By the way, isn't there any way you could get access to the domain? If it belongs to you you could contact your supplier to change it for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could use htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.bar.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Save this in a file called .htaccess and place it in the root of www.foo.com

Comment: I don't have access to www.foo.com, i can only work within www.bar.com

Comment: I remember when I had a similar situation, if I remember correctly you have to change something in the dns settings.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options: [Apache mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), or PHP header magic, as shown by Michiel Pater.

mod_alias:

```
 Redirect / http://www.bar.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

then, the only solution available to you is javascript-based one

most common way is

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--

if (window != top) top.location.href = location.href;

// -->
</SCRIPT>
```